# When ETag validation returns a 304, does the browser automatically fetch from the cache?

Tags: caching, cache-control, etag, http-status-code-304

I have never worked with etag before and I am trying to implement it to a call related to fetching a config JSON. On the preliminary response, I set a cache-control of 1 hour and I also receive the etag, which I store in the localstorage. On my subsequent request, I add if `If-None-Match` header with the etag value I retrieved from the localstorage. As expected I received a 304, which the request handler treats as an error. I presumed that a 304 would be handled by the browser automatically and would fetch the cached version from my previous request. If this is not the case, how should I handle the 304 correctly to fetch the cached value correctly?

Answer (score 2):

`304`'s are not error responses they are valid responses.

If your code is handling this as an error then your code should be updated to accept this as a valid response and use the cache value that's already stored. Normally this is hidden from you at the browser level where it would handle requesting the data, if the cache is fresh it will give you the cache value and if its stale it will give you the value returned from the (normally) `200` response.

If your manually making a call (i.e using `Javascript` / `XHR`) and manually populating headers, then your starting to get into the realm of managing your own cache if your modifying headers and using `ETags`.

If your not manually changing headers and instead relying on the browsers own cache handling just make sure your JavaScript library is setup to use handle this (i.e if your using jQuery then check that the `cache` value is true).

Some additional information about your language/client side setup/libraries would be helpful.

Comment: I am working with node and node automatically sets etags on generating response. The requests on the clientside are handled using a package called axios. I had to set If-None-Match manually, unless there is a better way of handling it.